# control the number of decimal places in SAS proc means

Tags: sas, decimal, proc

I am trying to report my proc means output with 10 decimal places by specifying maxdec=10. However, SAS does not report more than 7 decimal places.
Here is the warning I get:
WARNING: NDec value is inappropriate, BEST format will be used.
I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, it states that MEANS will print out 0-8 decimal places based on the value of MAXDEC.  If you want more, you will need to save the results and print them yourself.

Try this:

```
data test;
format x 12.11;
do i=1 to 1000;
   x = rannor(0);
   output;
end;
drop i;
run;

proc means data=test noprint;
var x;
output out=means_out mean=mean std=std;
run;

proc print data=means_out noobs;
var mean std;
format mean std 12.11;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, `maxdec=` works for limiting the number of decimal places below 8. `Proc means` isn't going to let you do too much to change the format of the summary statistics. I'd suggest using `proc tabulate`:

If your `proc means` looks like:

```
proc means data=yourdata;
  var yourvariable;
run;
```

Than use something like:

```
proc tabulate data=yourdata;
    var yourvariable;
    table yourvariable*
      (n
      mean*format=15.10
      stddev*format=15.10
      min*format=15.10
      max*format=15.10);
run;
```